# Java- Why is mouse movement causing the frame to update?

Tags: java, swing

So, after messing around for a good hour trying to figure out why my JPanel was flickering when moving my mouse I found out that that wasn't the case at all. From what I found out, from changing the order im drawing images, was that the buffer image is being drawn before everything is done being drawn to it. I can only assume that moving my mouse somehow causes the image to be drawn before the render cycle is finished. Im drawing everything to a separate image, overriding a JPanels paintComponent method, then letting the JFrame paint the panel. Moving the frame or resizing it causes the same thing but im not worried about those.

```
public void render() {
    Graphics g = screen.getGraphics();

    // State based system, renders all subsequent images
    Manager.render(g);

    // For fading between state changes
    g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, Variables.alpha));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, Variables.frame.getWidth(), Variables.frame.getHeight());

    // Only way that worked to get the frame to update the JPanel
    Variables.frame.repaint();
}

public static void generateFrame(String title, int width, int height, boolean resize, KeyListener keys,
        MouseListener mouse, MouseMotionListener mMotion, MouseWheelListener mWheel) {

    frame = new JFrame(title);

    frame.setResizable(resize);
    frame.addKeyListener(keys);
    frame.addMouseListener(mouse);
    frame.addMouseMotionListener(mMotion);
    frame.addMouseWheelListener(mWheel);    
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            shutdown();
        }
    });

    pane = new JPanel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7796800583217917918L;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(Variables.screen, -Variables.xOffset, -Variables.yOffset,
                    Variables.frame.getWidth() + Variables.yOffset * 2,
                    Variables.frame.getHeight() + Variables.xOffset * 2, null);
        }

    };
    frame.add(Variables.pane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true); 

}
```

Comment: Because, that's what mouse movement does, it may require portions of the UI to be updated in response to it's passing - Without out more context - I'd be worried about `Graphics g = screen.getGraphics();` and `Manager.render(g);` but I don't know what they are attached to - Remember, Swing uses a passive rendering engine, this means that paints may occur at any time for any reason

Comment: So it looks like you're drawing on a different thread? You can't predict when the repaint occurs - there may be many reasons. The only way to get this done right with threads is to use double buffering (you draw updates to one BufferedImage but you show the other BufferedImage on the screen, and you swap them around when they're done). Make the variable (`screen`) that refers to the BufferedImage `volatile` or always update and read the `screen` variable while `synchronized` on one object)

Comment: Post code we can run.. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I fixed it by just adding another buffer for the entire frame between the panel and the original buffer.